# Mysql selecting records from two different tables the following way

Tags: mysql

I want to run a query on two tables (jobs & jobs_applictions) and fetch total number of applications associated with each job.

Tables structure is:

jobs table

| job_id | job_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | System Analyst |
| 2 | Web Developer |
| 3 | Software Developer |

applications table

| app_id | job_id | application_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12-Jan-2023 |
| 2 | 1 | 12-Jan-2023 |
| 3 | 1 | 14-Jan-2023 |
| 4 | 2 | 14-Jan-2023 |
| 5 | 3 | 14-Jan-2023 |
| 6 | 3 | 15-Jan-2023 |
| 7 | 3 | 15-Jan-2023 |
| 8 | 3 | 15-Jan-2023 |

The expected result is:

| job_id | job_title | total_no_applications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | System Analyst | 3 |
| 2 | Web Developer | 1 |
| 3 | Software Developer | 4 |

The query I was trying with some combinations COUNT DISTINCTIVE but I was unable to figure out and search on this platform did not fetch me the expected results.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a join aggregation approach we can try:

```sql
SELECT j.job_id, j.job_title, COUNT(a.job_id) AS total_no_applications
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN applications a
    ON a.job_id = j.job_id
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1;
```